# Having an issue running Python Code in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, torch, librosa

Hi everyone so I have some python code I am trying to run from my terminal (will not work in an IDE) to take a .mp3 file and classify the genre of the song based on the Spectrogram that we are using the librosa library plugin for. The code is from this gitHub: https://github.com/cetinsamet/music-genre-classification .When I use the command prompt specified by the gitHub user who created this app I get this error in my terminal:

```
(base) Nicos-MacBook-Pro:src nico$ python3 get_genre.py ../test.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_genre.py", line 61, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "get_genre.py", line 30, in main
    net.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODELPATH, map_location='cpu'))
  File "/Users/nico/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 419, in load
    f = open(f, 'rb')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../utils/net.pt'
```

---

Here is the command line specified: $ python3 get_genre.py ../test.mp3

Comment: What do you understand from the error message? Isn’t it rather clear-cut? Also, I see you calling that `open()`, use a context manager ;)

Answer (score 2):

The error message quite plainly tells you that the code depends on having a file `../utils/net.pt`

Comment: I changed the path name to correct it but now I am getting this error:  raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape ()